# Is it good practice to use and include <limits>?

Tags: c++

I have validated `cin` input by using `std::numeric_limits` and thus I need to include `<limits>`.

Will this effect the functionality of my Program?

I have been reading so many comments on different forums that using `<limits>` is not a good practice, but nobody cleared stated why it is not a good practice. If it is really a bad practice, what is a good practice to validate `cin` input for known errors, such as **invalid inputs** and **long inputs**?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

void initMenu ();
void initDecision(int);
double areaCircle (double);
double areaRectangle (double, double);
const double PI = 4.14;
bool isValid (string);

int main()
{
    int choice;
    char cont;
    do
    {
        system ("cls");
        initMenu ();
        while (!(cin >> choice))
        {
            cin.clear();
            system ("cls");
            initMenu();
            cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
            cout << "Invalid Input cleared and turns to [" << cin.rdstate() << "] you can try it again or go to school" << '\n';
            cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        initDecision (choice);
        do
        {
            cin.clear();
            cout << "" << '\n';
            cout << "------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
            cout << "Do you want to continue using the Program? [Y/n]" << '\n';
            cout << "------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
            cin >> cont;
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        while (cont != 'Y' && cont != 'y' && cont != 'N' && cont != 'n' );
        system ("cls");
        cout << "-------------------------------" << '\n';
        cout << "Thank you for using our Program" << '\n';
        cout << "-------------------------------" << '\n';
    }
    while (cont == 'Y' || cont == 'y');
    return 0;
}

void initMenu()
{
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
    cout << "Choose any one option from above! [1] [2] [3] [4]" << '\n';
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
    cout << "1 Circle" << '\n';
    cout << "2 Rectangle" << '\n';
}

void initDecision(int choice)
{
    double r, a, b, h;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter the Radius of a Circle: " << '\n';
            do {cin >> r;} while (!isValid("Wrong Input detected, Try again!"));
            areaCircle(r);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Enter Base and Height of a Rectangle: " << '\n';
            do {cin >> b >> h;} while (!isValid("Wrong Input detected, Try again!"));
            areaRectangle(b ,h);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
            cout << "The option is out of bound, Check and try again with available options" << '\n';
            cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------" << '\n';

        break;
    }
}

double areaCircle (double r)
{
    double result = PI * r * r;
    cout << "The area of a circle that has value: [" << r << "] = [" << result << "]" << '\n';
    return result;
}

double areaRectangle (double b, double h)
{
    double result =  b * h;
    cout << "Rectangle with Base value: [" << b << "] and value of Height: [" << h << "] = [" << result << "]" << '\n';
    return result;
}

bool isValid (string error_msg)
{
    if(cin.rdstate())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() , '\n');
        system("cls");
        initMenu();
        cout << error_msg << '\n';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. I think you've misunderstood some piece of advice you were given.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is sometimes considered bad practise. Maybe that is what you are getting confused about?

Comment: Fine, with PI = 4.14 ? ;-)

Comment: @john Ok Cleared )

Comment: @john No, it was about #including <limits>

Comment: @Jeffrey yes Fine ;)

Comment: Why would it not be good practise to include a perfectly standard header file?

Comment: @john They were talking that it will break platform independence's

Comment: That is not true at all.

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes the concept is already cleared and I don't have cockroaches about this mystery anymore.

Comment: The only concern I know of is it can be a bit of a waste to waiting for billions of bytes if you're reading a corrupted datastream that never provides the character you're looking for. If you haven't found the end of a line of text in a few k, you can probably give up and get on with your life. In general, some sort of timeout is a good idea, if only to exit the program or thread when requested.

Comment: @user4581301 So it must not be use? if yes it must not be use than what is the alternative and how to handle the cin ?

Comment: I think you should focus your question about the pros and cons of this particular line in your code: `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` (if I understand your doubts), rather than incuding or not `<limits>` (which is kind of an odd question).

Comment: @Bob__  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');  will not work without including <limits>  and  it has any negative effects on the code according to your experience?

Comment: Again, the include part is not the "issue" here, but the *use* of it. Just consider @user4581301's comment.

Comment: @Bob__ All Clear, I will take care of that )

Comment: Using perfectly standard header file is a good idea, while consider using const double PI = 3.14;  instead of 4.14 ;-)

Comment: @Саша Ok all clear ;)

Comment: The whole point of input validation is to provide a sanity check on the input before allowing the program to do something stupid with bad data. A user hitting buttons on a keyboard trying to make a program work sooner or later will hit enter and get you out of a brutally long ignore. This I see as safe. In a production environment you may want to ignore, say, a maximum of 256 and then reconsider your options or perform a few other tasks before ignoring another 256. It all depends on context.

Comment: @user4581301 hmm I will see that option also, thank you )